# Dynamically generate criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Users table that contains dozens of columns like date of birth, year of vehicle owned, make and model of the vehicle, color and many other personal fields unrelated to the vehicle

There's also a 2nd table called Coupons that needs to be designed in a way to support a qualification like "user qualifies if younger than 30 yrs old", "user qualifies if vehicle is greater than 10 yrs old", "user qualifies if vehicle color is green".

When a user logs in, I need to present all coupons the user qualifies for. The problem that I'm having is that the coupon qualifications could be numerous, could have qualifiers like equal, greater than or less than and may have different combinations.

My only solution at this point is to store the actual sql string within one of the coupons table columns like

```
select * from Users where UserId = SOME_PLACEHOLDER and VehicleYear < 10
```

Then I could execute the sql for each coupon row and return true or false. Seems very inefficient as I would potentially have to execute 1000s of sql statements for each coupon code.

Any insight, help is appreciated. I do have server-side code where I could potentially be able to do looping.

Thank you.

Comment: @gsogoly - I was going to change it to "Dynamically generate criteria in SQL", but you were to quick for me.

Comment: Why do you have vehicle information in a Users table?

Comment: Seconding @TomH.  This sounds like a fishy database design.  What happens if a user has more than one vehicle?  What else might qualify a user for coupon offers in the future?

Comment: This was just an example. I actually do have a separate table but did not want to muddy the water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult problem.  Seems like users will be added at high volume speed, with coupons at a fairly regular frequency.

Adding SQL to a table to be used dynamically is workable - at least you'll get a fresh execution plan - BUT your plan cache may balloon up.

I have a feeling that running a single coupon for all users is probably likely to be your highest performing query because it's one single set of criteria which will be fairly selective on users first and total number of coupons is small, whereas running all coupons for a single user is separate criteria for each coupon for that user.  Running all coupons for all users may still perform well, even though it's effectively a cross join first - I guess it is just going to depend.

Anyway, the case for all coupons for all users (or sliced either way, really) will be something like this:

```
SELECT user.id, coupon.id
FROM user
INNER JOIN coupon
ON (
    CASE WHEN <coupon.criteria> THEN <coupon.id> -- code generated from the coupon rules table
    CASE WHEN <coupon.criteria> THEN <coupon.id> -- etc.
    ELSE NULL
) = coupon.id
```

To generate the coupon rules, you can relatively easily do the string concatenation in a single swipe (and you can combine an individual rule lines design for a coupon with AND with a further inner template):

```
DECLARE @outer_template AS varchar(max) = 'SELECT user.id, coupon.id
    FROM user
    INNER JOIN coupon
    ON (
        {template}
        ELSE NULL
    ) = coupon.id
';

DECLARE @template AS varchar(max) = 'CASE WHEN {coupon.rule} THEN {coupon.id}{crlf}';

DECLARE @coupon AS TABLE (id INT, [rule] varchar(max));
INSERT INTO @coupon VALUES
    (1, 'user.Age BETWEEN 20 AND 29')
    ,(2, 'user.Color = ''Yellow''');


DECLARE @sql AS varchar(MAX) = REPLACE(
           @outer_template
           ,'{template}',
REPLACE((
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
           @template
           ,'{coupon.rule}', coupon.[rule])
           , '{coupon.id}', coupon.id)
FROM @coupon AS coupon
FOR XML PATH('')
), '{crlf}', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)));

PRINT @sql;
// EXEC (@sql);
```

There's ways to pretty that up - play with it here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115098/

I would consider adding computed columns (possibly persisted and indexed) to assist.  For instance, age - non-persisted computed column will likely perform better than a scalar function.

I would consider batching this with a table which says whether a coupon is valid for a user and when it was last validated.

Seems like ages can change and a user can become valid or invalid for a coupon as their birthday passes.

When a user logs in you could spawn a background job to update their coupons.  On subsequent logons, there won't be any need to update (since it's not likely to change until the next day or a triggering event).

Just a few ideas.

I would also add that you should have a way to test a coupon before it is approved to ensure there are no syntax errors (since the SQL is ad hoc or arbitrary) - this can be done relatively easily - perhaps a test user table (test_user as user in the generated code template instead) is required to contain pass and fail rows and the coupon rule points to those.  Not only does the EXEC have to work - the rows it returns should be the expected and only the expected rows for that coupon.

Comment: What an awesome idea. Would like to thank everyone who provided input as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem.  Here are some quick ideas that may help depending on your domain requirements:

1. Restrict the type of criteria you will be filtering on so that you can use dynamic or non-dynamic sql to execute them efficiently.  For example if you are going to only have integers between a range of min and max values as a criteria then the problem becomes simpler.  (You only need to know the field name, and the min max values to describe a criterian, not the full where statement.)
2. Create a number of views which expose the attributes in a helpful way.  Then perform queries against those views -- or have those views pre-select in some way.  For example, an age group view that has a field which can contain the values `< 21`, `21-30`, `30-45`, `>45`.  Then your select just needs to return the rows from this view that match these strings.
3. Create a table which stores the results of running your criteria matching query (This can be run off line by a back ground process).  Then for a given user check for membership by looking where in the table this user's ID exists.

Thinking about this some more I realize all my suggestions are based on one idea.

A query for an individual user will work faster overall if you first perform an SQL query against all users and cache that result in some way.  If every user is reproducing queries against the whole dataset you will lose efficiency.  You need some way to cache results and reuse them.

Hope this helps -- comment if these ideas are not clear.

Comment: Thank you. The dynamic criteria is known at the time I create a coupon so I have control over how I design it. Regarding 1) not that simple, could be integers, string, etc 2) Seems like I would need 1000s of views 3)Users can be created every second so storing results is not an option as I won't be able to do that on a nightly basis or some other frequency. I think I need something with Case statements or some other long sql. Hmm

Comment: @gsogoly - sounds like your only choice is dynamic sql -- but it will be slow.  Any caching you can do will speed up the system.

Comment: Yep. At this point, I'm not even worried about performance. Just hoping for a solution that I can optimize later :) Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought on an approach (similar to Hogan's) would be to test for coupon applicability at the time the coupon is created. Store those results in a table (`User_Coupons` for example). If any user data is changed, your system would then retest any changed users for which coupons are applicable to them. At coupon creation (or change) time it would only check versus that coupon. At use creation (or change) time it would only check versus that user.

The coupon criteria should be from a known set of possible criteria and any time that you want to add a new *type* of criteria, it would possibly involve a code change. For example, let's say that you have a table set up similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Coupon_Criteria (
    coupon_id        INT         NOT NULL,
    age_minimum      SMALLINT    NULL,
    age_maximum      SMALLINT    NULL,
    vehicle_color    VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_Coupon_Criteria PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (coupon_id)
)
```

If you wanted to add the ability to base a coupon on vehicle age then you would have to add a column to the table and likewise you would have to adjust your search code. You would use NULL values to indicate that the criteria is unused for that coupon.

An example query for the above table:

```
SELECT
    CC.coupon_id
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN Coupon_Criteria CC ON
    (CC.age_maximum IS NULL OR dbo.f_GetAge(U.birthday) <= age_maximum) AND
    (CC.age_minimum IS NULL OR dbo.f_GetAge(U.birthday) >= age_minimum) AND
    (CC.vehicle_color IS NULL OR U.vehicle_color = CC.vehicle_color) AND
    ...
```

This can get unwieldy if the number of possible criteria gets to be very large.

Another possibility would be to save the coupon criteria in XML and have a business object for your application use that to determine eligibility. It could use the XML to generate a proper query against the User table (and any other necessary tables).

Comment: I see what you're doing here and I'm ok  creating a table that stores the different criteria and I'm ok adding or removing those when time changes. However, what do I do when one coupon requires < 30 yrs old and the other coupon that says > 30 yrs old. Not every coupon uses the same logical operator. I think we're getting close here.

Comment: That's why I have min and max columns. Rather than look at those as the same criteria with different operators, look at them as completely different criteria.

Comment: Just have hard time from a maintenance perspective. Every time there's a new column, have to update the criteria table ddl as well but definitely something to think about. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I was just thinking about another possible option, which I'll also add. It would be less maintenance, possibly good performance, but a bit tricky and could be error prone if you're not careful.

Comment: Also, found this article - http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html - that may help me sort things out. Very long so may take a while.

Comment: Erland has some great stuff. I don't think that anything in there will directly apply to what you're doing, but it may lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility. Each criteria could be given a query template which you could append to your queries. This would just involve updates to the data instead of DDL and could have good performance. It would involve dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Coupons (
    coupon_id    INT              NOT NULL,
    description  VARCHAR(2000)    NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_Coupons PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (coupon_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Coupon_Criteria (
    coupon_id        INT             NOT NULL,
    criteria_num     SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
    description      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    code_template    VARCHAR(500)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Coupon_Criteria PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (coupon_id, criteria_num),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Coupon_Criteria_Coupon FOREIGN KEY (coupon_id) REFERENCES Coupons (coupon_id)
)

INSERT INTO Coupons (coupon_id, description)
VALUES (1, 'Young people save $200 on yellow vehicles!')

INSERT INTO Coupon_Criteria (coupon_id, criteria_num, description, code_template)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Young people', 'dbo.Get_Age(U.birthday) <= 20')
INSERT INTO Coupon_Criteria (coupon_id, criteria_num, description, code_template)
VALUES (1, 2, 'Yellow Vehicles', U.vehicle_color = ''Yellow''')
```

You could then build a query by simply concatenating all of the criteria for any given coupon. The **big** downside to this one is that it's only one-directional. Given a coupon you can easily find who is qualified for it, but given a user you cannot find all coupons for which they are eligible except by going through all of the coupons. My guess is that the second is what you'd probably be most interested in unfortunately. Maybe this will give you some other ideas though.

For example, you could potentially have it work the other way by having a set number of criteria in a table and for the coupon/criteria linking table indicate whether or not that criteria is active. When querying you could then include that in your query. In other words, the query would look something like:

```
WHERE
    (CC.is_active = 0 OR <code from the code column>) AND
```

The querying gets very complex though since you either need to join once for every possible criteria or you need to query to compare the number of active requirements for a coupon versus the number that are fulfilled. That is possible in SQL, but it's similar to working with an EAV model - which is basically what this turns into: a variation on an EAV model (yuck)

Comment: This looks much better. Love updating the data as opposed to ddl. Just to reiterate, I'm looking for coupons that are eligible for a single logged-in user. You are on the right track. So given the is_Active logic, how would you build the dynamic sql?